# Why the height of recursion tree is $\log_b n$?

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I'm studying algorithm analysis by "Introduction to alogrithm".

What I'm learning is proof by recursion tree but I can't understand how can I calculate height of recursion tree.

So I searched stackoverflow and found the answer but there was no details.

[How to determine the height of a recursion tree from a recurrence relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475002/9437175)

Can you explain why $\log_b n$ can be depth(height)?

Comment: How many times can you divide $n$ by $b$ before reaching $1?$.

Comment: That's what I want to know. How I compute that?

Comment: @haram, **Hint:** With $b$ fixed, you need to solve $b^k\leq n\lt b^{k+1}$ for $k$ (this is the height of the tree, or more explicitly, the height is $\lfloor k\rfloor$ or $\lceil k\rceil$ depending upon convention/context).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas In your explanation, n is the number of all nodes of recursion tree?

Comment: Yes, it's the same $n$ you're talking about and $b$ is for the number of recursive calls at each node (similar to what happens in a $b$-ary tree)

Comment: In expression $a*T(n/b)+f(n)$, $T(n/b)$ means what?